# Is there a PEP484 type hint for 'character'?

Tags: python, type-hinting

In short: is there a Python type hint for 'character', representing a length-one `str` but not using the type hint `str`?

I saw `chr` used recently for this purpose, and other than intuition I can't find anything to prove or disprove that this is appropriate. It's apparently valid Python syntax. By example,

```
>>> def foo(c: chr):
...   pass
... 
>>> foo('a')
>>>
```

This raises more questions than it answers: is `chr` considered a valid type hint because it's a callable, and all types are "callable" by their constructors? Seems no - some quick experiments show that Python will in fact accept any defined symbol as a type hint, regardless of whether it makes sense.

Comment: No, because that is not a type. using `chr` is simply wrong, because that is certainly not a type.

Comment: There is no character type. A length-one str is still a str.

Comment: Where did you see that? It may be a custom type.

Comment: @Selcuk it is not, it s a built-in function that takes an ordinal value and returns the "character" (i.e. length-1 string) it represents, essentially, the inverse function of `ord`

Comment: He's referring to my answer on CodeReview [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/230129/153917)

Comment: Just because a type hint is valid syntax doesn't make it correct. Far from it.

Comment: Right; I'm coming to understand that Python has a functionally useless tolerance for what goes into a type hint.

Comment: @Reinderien they are *hints*, to be used by third-party things. If you actually need static-time type checking, for example, you would need something like `mypy`.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4334

Comment: @SolomonUcko Considering I asked the question before that one, shouldn't it be the one closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @Reinderien https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814285/type-hint-for-a-char-character-type has a superset of the answers, though. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using one of the following methods. Nearly all of them are related to the use of the `typing` module :

- If you already know which letters the user can pass, then a great way would be to use the `typing.Literal` object. I highly recommend studying the example from the documentation - [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal). Note that this hint should be used only if all possible values are known in advance (look at the example again);
- If there is no such knowledge - for example, when any single character can be used, then an equally good way would be to use `typing.TypeVar` - [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). It will be possible to do something in the following spirit:

```
import typing

char = typing.TypeVar("char", str)


def foo(c: char) -> ...:
    # TODO
```

Moreover, do not forget to put `str` as an argument when defining `char`. It means that `char` can be any subtype of `str`.

- In the end, the natural annotation `str` will never fail. It will be enough to specify in the docstring that the expected argument is a single character.