# Type hint for a "char" / "character" type

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

There is no built-in, primitive type for "char" or "character" so obviously a string of length 1 will have to be used. But to connote this and to connote it should be treated as if it was a character how can this be achieved through a type hint?

```
grade: chr = 'A'
```

One approach may be to use the built-in 'chr' function to connote this.

```
grade: "char" = 'A'
grade: "character" = 'A'
```

Another approach may be to use a string type hint to connote this.

To my understanding there is no object connoting a char type in the 'typing' module.

Other posts I have searched for either state why certain type-hints (like using the 'chr' built in function to connote a character) are simply wrong:
[Is there a PEP484 type hint for 'character'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229400/is-there-a-pep484-type-hint-for-character)

However, none have given an answer as to what should be used to connote a char. Using a 'str' typehint and documenting it should be treated as if it were a character is not an answer I am looking for.

```
grade: str = 'A'  # Treat as if it were a character
```

I would like to know what should I use to connote a "char" / "character" type in python?

Edit for clarity: I am asking for a type-hint not additional computation or anything more... If I was asking for a string length check or some sort of variation of that I would not have asked this question.

Comment: If this is for letter grades then perhaps you could use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead? It can be used for type hinting and it will limit the user from adding the wrong string.

Comment: @liveware the example given of a grade was purely for example purposes. Im asking in general, what should be used to connote a char.

Comment: I believe you can technically use `Literal["\u0000", "\u0001", "\u0002", "\u0003", …]`, but this will be rather long.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is simply wrong. `chr` is a built-in function, it's not a type ! So you can't use it in type hints.

In my opinion it is enough to say it's a `str`.Type hint is for third-parties, type-checkers... When Python doesn't differentiate between *char* and *string*, why do you want to do that? You can then implement a logic to raise error in your function or methods or whatever if that string has more than one item.

If you insist, you can have your custom type although I don't think it is super useful:

```py
class Onechar(str):
    def __new__(cls, s):
        if len(s) > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one character")
        return super(Onechar, cls).__new__(cls, s)

obj: Onechar
obj = "hiii"       # mypy complains
obj = Onechar("h") # fine
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str` annotated with a custom type with `__instancecheck__` overridden:

```py
from typing import Annotated


class MetaChar(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance: str):
        return isinstance(instance, str) and len(instance) == 1


class Char(str, metaclass=MetaChar):
    pass


print(isinstance('a', Char))
print(isinstance('ab', Char))
print(isinstance(42, Char))
print(isinstance(1, Char))


Chr = Annotated[str, Char]


def foo(char: Chr) -> None:
    print(char)


foo('a')
```

But I don't think that any type checker already supports this.
Also, this is a lot of code for just a type hint.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recently answered [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229400/is-there-a-pep484-type-hint-for-character), so I'll just copy my answer. I would recommend using one of the following methods. Nearly all of them are related to the use of the `typing` module :

- If you already know which letters the user can pass, then a great way would be to use the `typing.Literal` object. I highly recommend studying the example from the documentation - [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal). Note that this hint should be used only if all possible values are known in advance (look at the example again);
- If there is no such knowledge - for example, when any single character can be used, then an equally good way would be to use `typing.TypeVar` - [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). It will be possible to do something in the following spirit:

```
import typing

char = typing.TypeVar("char", str)


def foo(c: char) -> ...:
    # TODO
```

Moreover, do not forget to put `str` as an argument when defining `char`. It means that `char` can be any subtype of `str`.

- In the end, the natural annotation `str` will never fail. It will be enough to specify in the docstring that the expected argument is a single character.